# ordering data in query vs in UI

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm pulling activity from an Oracle database, sorted by timestamp. The code I have works well, but I'm wondering if it's actually efficient. Should I be ordering the data in the database via the `order by aa.timestamp desc` line, or should I remove that line and add code to sort the data once I've already pulled it?

Here's my code for reference.

```
    private void aaButton_Click
    {
        string commandText = @"select u.firstname, u.lastname, cm.course_id, cc.title as content_title, aa.data, aa.timestamp, 
        aa.status, aa.session_id, aa.messages from BBLEARN.activity_accumulator aa 
        join BBLEARN.users u ON aa.user_pk1 = u.pk1 
        join BBLEARN.course_main cm ON aa.course_pk1 = cm.pk1 
        left join BBLEARN.course_contents cc on cc.pk1 = aa.content_pk1
        where " + userType + " = '" + aa_userBox.Text + @"'
        and " + courseType + " = '" + aa_courseBox.Text + @"'
        and aa.timestamp >= '" + GetDate(aa_startDate) + @"'
        and aa.timestamp <= '" + GetDateAfter(aa_endDate) + @"'
        order by aa.timestamp desc";

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => GetActData(commandText));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void GetActData(string selectCommand)
    {

        //open the connection
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectString);
        conn.Open();

        //define the command
        selectCommand = selectCommand.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
        OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand, conn);
        OracleCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OracleCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        //run the command
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);                        
        Invoke(new Action(() => actGridView.DataSource = table));

        //resize the dataGridView
        Invoke(new Action(() => actGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)));


        //close the connection
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: ordering at database level is required for paging. For your specific case (no paging) it seems to be opinion based.

Comment: if you have pagination, ordering in the database can sort all data in all pages, while ordering in the front end only sort the data on specific page, it depends on the requirement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the number of records being returned has a lot to do with the right answer to this question, but there are other forces in play.  If the number of records is relatively small, then it probably doesn't matter.  All modern sorting algorithms have average case O(n log n) sorting algorithms and should work fine on small datasets.

If the number if sufficiently large (say 100,000 or more, for example), then I'd be hard pressed to believe that the UI (or even LINQ) could out-perform the database in ordering data, unless the DB server itself is grossly undersized or saturated.  However, if the data will likely be re-sorted in the UI anyway, then you may question the value of pre-sorting at the database level to begin with.

Also, as an aside, not that I endorse inline SQL, but if you're going to do something like that you may want to consider using stringbuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("select");
sb.AppendLine("u.firstname, u.lastname, cm.course_id, cc.title content_title,";
sb.AppendLine("aa.data, aa.timestamp, aa.status, aa.session_id, aa.messages");
```

And you would call it with:

```
sb.ToString();
```

Also, when possible, especially with Oracle and it's picky nature of date-time formats, you really ought to use bind variables instead of literals for your timestamp range.  And of course, this will also prevent SQL injection, but the ability to pass native data types is the big selling point for me.  Not only that, but for large numbers of transactions, you will be much kinder to the shared pool by using bind variables.

Comment: Clear and concise. Thank you.